# Help needed with the fitting and bug

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

```
rData={{5.3571429,0.096854535},{10.714286,0.055104186},{16.071429,0.042811499},{21.428571,0.024825886},{26.785714,0.023279183},{32.142857,0.016328542},{37.5,0.0092185037},{42.857143,0.0075624777},{48.214286,0.0023514323},{53.571429,0.001637045},{58.928571,-0.0024887011},{64.285714,-0.0034741333},{69.642857,-0.0056340032},{75,-0.0040906991},{80.357143,-0.0039738424},{85.714286,-0.0044593789},{91.071429,-0.0054884315},{96.428571,-0.0037277341},{101.78571,-0.0041691748},{107.14286,-0.0039292558},{112.5,-0.0037408923},{117.85714,-0.0040700255},{123.21429,-0.0028904555},{128.57143,-0.0022557232},{133.92857,-0.0020756487},{139.28571,-0.0020739949},{144.64286,-0.0015149035},{150,-0.0019796368},{155.35714,-0.00068430865},{160.71429,-0.00060721168},{166.07143,-0.00055972397},{171.42857,-0.0011788755},{176.78571,-0.00090675531},{182.14286,-0.00060012026},{187.5,7.6071311*10^-6}};

tData={{5.3571429,0.081473653},{10.714286,-0.0076210718},{16.071429,-0.038565046},{21.428571,-0.014000405},{26.785714,-0.042161254},{32.142857,-0.071404281},{37.5,-0.066992712},{42.857143,-0.031355057},{48.214286,-0.02043848},{53.571429,-0.025259291},{58.928571,-0.019615094},{64.285714,-0.015185751},{69.642857,-0.012213914},{75,-0.0047624032},{80.357143,-0.00041652762},{85.714286,0.0028162852},{91.071429,0.00979253},{96.428571,0.0080315783},{101.78571,0.0034739882},{107.14286,0.0021786814},{112.5,0.0043349925},{117.85714,0.0053397331},{123.21429,0.0061087654},{128.57143,0.0028425693},{133.92857,0.002129577},{139.28571,0.0068534431},{144.64286,0.0071201038},{150,0.0099290536},{155.35714,0.0089545127},{160.71429,0.0079282308},{166.07143,0.0075533041},{171.42857,0.01092774},{176.78571,0.012219652},{182.14286,0.01013098},{187.5,0.0096622622}};

(*Extract x and y values*)
rXValues = rData[[All, 1]];
rYValues = rData[[All, 2]];

tXValues = tData[[All, 1]];
tYValues = tData[[All, 2]];

(*Define the equations*)
\[Alpha][\[Mu]_, \[Lambda]_] := 1/(2*\[Mu] + \[Lambda]);
eqns[\[Mu]_, \[Lambda]_, ke_, 
   ko_] := {x^2*r''[x] + x*r'[x] - 
     r[x] + \[Alpha][\[Mu], \[Lambda]]^-1*ke^2*x^2*
      r[x] - \[Alpha][\[Mu], \[Lambda]]^-1*ko^2*x^2*\[Theta][x] == 0, 
   x^2*\[Theta]''[x] + 
     x*\[Theta]'[x] - \[Theta][x] + \[Mu]^-1*ko^2*x^2*r[x] + \[Mu]^-1*
      ke^2*x^2*\[Theta][x] == 0};

(*Define the model*)
model[\[Mu]_, \[Lambda]_, ke_, ko_] := 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqns[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko], 
    r[0.75] == 0.1625, \[Theta][0.75] == 0, 
    r[187.5] == 0, \[Theta][187.5] == 0}, {r[x], \[Theta][x]}, {x, 
    0.75, 187.5}, {\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko}];

(*Fit the data with initial guess values*)
initialGuess = {{\[Mu], 15}, {\[Lambda], 50}, {ke, 0.01}, {ko, 
    0.01}};
fit = NonlinearModelFit[rYValues, 
   model[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko][[1]][x], initialGuess, x, 
   MaxIterations -> 10000];
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[tYValues, 
   model[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko][[2]][x], initialGuess, x, 
   MaxIterations -> 10000];

(*Plot the fitted functions*)enter code here
Show[Plot[fit[x], {x, 0.75, 187.5}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLabel -> "Fitted r(x)", AxesLabel -> {"x", "r(x)"}], 
 ListPlot[rData, PlotStyle -> Blue]]

Show[Plot[fit2[x], {x, 0.75, 187.5}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLabel -> "Fitted \[Theta](x)", 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Theta](x)"}], 
 ListPlot[tData, PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

I am trying to fit the two data sets using a coupled differential equations and fitting parameters. However, Getting an error like that:
"The function value is not a list of real numbers with dimensions and 0.75 is not a valid variable."

How to fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your data, this will increase your chance to get helpful answers!

Comment: Please see my data files in my latest answer.

Comment: `model[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko][[1]][x]`  evaluates to `1[x]` what is wrong syntax.

Comment: Please elaborate this a bit.Letme know how to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but an extended comment with corrected code

Here I try to prepare the solution for `rData` . As mentioned by @DanialHuber  your `model` definition has syntax error

Try

```
funr = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqns[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko], 
r[0.75] == 0.1625, \[Theta][0.75] == 0,r[187.5] == 0, \[Theta][187.5] == 0}, 
r  , {x, 0.75, 187.5}, {\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko}];

initialGuess = {{\[Mu], 15}, {\[Lambda], 50}, {ke, 0.01}, {ko, 0.01}};
fit = NonlinearModelFit[rData, funr[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko]  [x],initialGuess, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

Evaluation of `fit` doesn't finish and gives an error

"ParametricNDSolveValue::bvluc: The equations derived from the boundary conditions are numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be sufficient to uniquely define a solution. If a solution is computed, it may match the boundary conditions poorly."

Please give some hints about your model, especialy about the boundary conditions that appear too restrictive!

**addendum**

Here an approach with generalized boundary conditions (two additional parameters!)

```
funr = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqns[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko], 
r[0.75] == 0.1625, \[Theta][0.75] == 0, 
r'[.75] == rs0, \[Theta]'[.75] == \[Theta]s0}, 
r, {x, 0.75, 187.5}, {\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko, rs0, \[Theta]s0}];

initialGuess = {{\[Mu], 15}, {\[Lambda], 50}, {ke, 0.01}, {ko, 0.01}};
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
rData, {funr[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko, rs0, \[Theta]s0][x], \[Mu] > 0, \[Lambda] > 0, ke > 0, ko > 0}, {\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko, rs0, \[Theta]s0}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`fit` runs without error but evaluation doesn't finish...

Comment: We can relax the boundary condition. It's a circular system. There is a inner boundary condition for r and theta are: r(x_in) = 0.1625 and
ϕ(x_in) = 0. At the outer boundary we assume r(x_out) = 0 and ϕ(x_out) = 0. The experimental data needs to fit with the solutions of the above coupled differential equation for r and theta. Hope it will help you to solve this

Comment: @random Why do you expect the model fits your data well?

Comment: I do not expect that. but i am getting some error. I want to solve this error first

Comment: My answer shows you runnable code without syntax errors(hopefully)

Comment: initialGuess = {{\[Mu], 15}, {\[Lambda], 50}, {ke, 0.01}, {ko, 
    0.01}};
fit = NonlinearModelFit[rData, funr[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko][x], 
  initialGuess, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[tData, funr[\[Mu], \[Lambda], ke, ko][x], 
   initialGuess, x, Method -> "NMinimize"];

 Changed this portion (as you suggested) but getting error again.

Comment: @random Which  error did you get?

Comment: The errors are following: 1. ParametricNDSolveValue::bvluc: The equations derived from the boundary conditions are numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be sufficient to uniquely define a solution. If a solution is computed, it may match the boundary conditions poorly. 2. ParametricNDSolveValue::berr: The scaled boundary value residual error of 1.332919502031455`*^25 indicates that the boundary values are not satisfied to specified tolerances. Returning the best solution found. 3. Further output of ParametricNDSolveValue::bvluc will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: These are the errors I mentioned in my answer!  See my addendum.